# How can I use attributes from a parent class in a child class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, tkinter

I am writing a chess program but don't quite understand inheritance. How can I use an attribute (empassant) from a parent class in a subclass?
My parent class is:

```py
class Pieces():
    def __init__(self, empassant=(-5,-5)):
        super().__init__()
        self.empassant=empassant
```

My subclass is:

```py
class White (Pieces):

    def __init__(self):
        #stuff
    def pawn(self, pieceposition):
        empassant=#empassant from the pieces class
```

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python class inherit tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call `super().__init__()` first in the `__init__` of the child

```
class White (Pieces):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #others initialization here

    def pawn(self, pieceposition):
        print(self.empassant)
```